# What's better, an empty non-nullable string or a null and nullable string?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Whether to choose a null nullable container or an empty non-nullable container can be settled [convincingly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69457387/700648).

A similar question appears to be harder to answer using the same argument. Quite likely both options are open.

Hence to answer this question you can take one of *three* positions.

We are all familiar (in C++, Java, ..) with the notion of a pointer in a linked list. There it is imperative that the pointer be nullable. That's our signal that we've reached the end of the list.

In Dart's syntax, we'd write `Item? next`. The "pointer" `next` is then nullable and will point to a sequel. Importantly, if there is none (at the end of the list), the value `null` is used as a legitimate and very clear semaphore to indicate so.

What about an even *easier* case, that of a simple `String`? Is it always clear that an empty non-nullable string is better than a null and nullable string? Is the converse true? The question may very well be opinion based, which is in itself an answer. (But it needs to be argued.) It may well be that one case is better in some circumstances and the other in others.

As usual, it's best to talk over concrete code. Anything else can easily become a waste of time. Here it goes.

Every `Employee` has a name, but not necessarily a boss. The CEO, at least, doesn't have one.

We then have two options. We could pinch our nose at using `String?` and minimize its use by writing `String boss`

```
class Employee {
  String name;
  String boss;
}
```

but that means that `boss` will sometimes be an empty string.

Or we could use `String?`

```
class Employee {
  String name;
  String? boss;
}
```

and pinch our nose at the continuing use of `null` to signal the lack of a boss.

What's better, an empty non-nullable string or a null and nullable string? Is this a style issue that can be resolved one way or the other?

Comment: You should use `null` to indicate data not being set. That would also help you to ensure you are always checking for `null`.

Comment: @julemand101 So you're voting for `if (boss == null)` (with `String? boss`) rather than `if (boss.isEmpty)` (with `String boss`). But the latter is just as brief. How did you reach this preference?

Comment: See my answer which explains my reasons better.

Comment: In fact it should be Employee not String... And you could create special empty Employee...

Comment: @Selvin Right... I did not mention how the `Employee`s are stored. If they are stored in a cross-linked list, as you believe they must be, then yes of course, it would have to be `Employee boss` (or `Employee? boss`). If one the other hand we're storing the employees in, say, `Map<String, Employee>` (to allow, for example, for an employee to be known only by name (for whatever reason; they're in a different organization, etc), then `String(?) boss` is the right way.

Comment: @Selvin but your point is not entirely off. You are addressing the case of a linked list (or tree, etc). In that case it's much clearer, and the type should surely be `Node? next` and never `Node next` or `String next`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `null` to indicate data which is optional so you can have the Dart type system help you making sure you are not going to use the value directly without first checking if the value have been defined.

It would not be smart to use empty strings since you are going to forget checking for the empty string at some point and get a runtime error (or undefined behavior) in your application which could have been prevented by using a nullable type.

It should in general be repeated: The use of `null` is totally fine. Null-safety in Dart has nothing to do with getting rid of `null` but to keep track of where `null` is a possible value and helping us making sure to check for `null` where it matters and only where it is actually a possibility.